# I can't print the default text in the Readline input

Tags: debian, perl, readline

I am writing an interface to my database and would like to be able to edit entries. I thought I'd use Readline, but can't get it work. I'd say my code should work, based on [Term::ReadLine::Gnu](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::ReadLine::Gnu#Modifying-Text) and [this answer on SE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33346124/6631810).

```
perl -w -MTerm::ReadLine -E'
$term = new Term::ReadLine "ProgramName";
$prompt = "prompt> ";
sub su {insert_text("----default----");};
$attributes = $term->Attribs;
$attributes{startup_hook} = \&su;
while (defined ($_ = $term->readline($prompt)))
{ eval; }
'
```

I'm getting the clean prompt:

```
prompt>
```

while I expect this:

```
prompt> ----default----
```

I'm still not very fluent with Perl, and this is getting complex. Is there a bug on my side? Is something missing? Or is it a hole in the module implementation?

Comment: Please compare this https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic and this https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Your question really fifits in with the second one.

Comment: @user1404316 They seem different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out I can use this syntax:

```
$term->readline($prompt, $default)
```

This is both much shorter and more simple than the code in the question.

I found it here: [Term::ReadLine::Perl5](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::ReadLine::Perl5), though I'm not yet sure how these three are related:

- Term::ReadLine::Perl5
- Term::ReadLine::Gnu
- Term::ReadLine

(The question stays open though.)

Comment: `Term::ReadLine` is a frontend module, `::Gnu`, `::Perl`, and `::Perl5` are implementations of the functionality, so you can normally just `use Term::ReadLine;` and not have to worry which implementation it is using behind the scenes.

Comment: @haukex Apparently this syntax works with `::Perl5`, but not with what I found (after installing Term::ReadLine) on my new OS before explicitly using Term::ReadLine::Perl5. (What was it?)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. As far as I can tell from a quick look at the [source](https://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/143b7de3f8fd2a2799ab2ce26ffefcf9596eadaa:/dist/Term-ReadLine/lib/Term/ReadLine.pm#l331), [`Term::ReadLine`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Term/ReadLine.html) only knows about `Term::ReadLine::Gnu`, `::EditLine`, and `::Perl`, but not `::Perl5`, which is probably why you need to load that one explicitly.